# Check multiple checkbox selection using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selection

I am trying to find the easiest way to get the checkboxes that are selected.

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='chkTextEffects']").change(function() {
        if ($("#cbSolid").is(':checked') == true) {
            alert('Solid');
        } else if ($("#cbOutline").is(':checked') == true) {
           alert('Outline');
        } else if ($("#cbSolid", "#cbOutline").is(':checked') == true) {
            alert('SolidOutline');
        } else if ($("#cbSolid", "#cbOutline").is(':checked') == false) {
            alert('No Effects'); 
        }
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkTextEffects" id="cbSolid" value="Solid" />Solid
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkTextEffects" id="cbOutline" value="Outline" />Outline
   <input id="TextEffectsSelection" type="hidden" />
```

I'm not sure about this line `if ($("#cbSolid", "#cbOutline").is(':checked') == true)` or should I use `bind` to get that worked.

Comment: Based on your demo, it looks like you are using checkboxes to mimic radio button behavior.  Your if/else if statements seem to confirm that you are only looking for a single selected element.  You probably want to use radio buttons instead.

Comment: @DanA-No,I want to get both the elements to be selected and sometimes may be one also.So based on that I need to get the checked one's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example I created that demonstrates what I think you're attempting to achieve:

```
$('#getCheckboxesButton').live('click', function(event) {
    var checkboxValues = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
        checkboxValues.push($(elem).val());
    });
    alert(checkboxValues.join(', '));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdvng/

Let me know if that helps.  Its basically using the ':checked' jQuery selector to retrieve checkboxes that are checked, then iterating through their values and printing it out.

Comment: @SuperPomodoro-Yes,Exactly this is what I need.Cheer :)

Comment: Additionally, you can use the :not selector to retrieve the checkboxes that are not checked.  jQuery selectors (and new CSS3 pseudo-selectors) allow for elegant DOM querying.

Comment: rhetorical question; but how did you get to the complete solution from this question LOL

Comment: @SuperPomodoro-Instead of button Click how could I get on selecting each individual checkbox.

Comment: @coder You've got the answer in your question. `$("input[name='chkTextEffects']").change(function() {//do stuff});` Every time one of your checkboxes changes state, a change event is triggered.

Comment: @coder As Craig mentioned, using the change() function will allow you to determine when the checkbox changes state.

Comment: @Craig As for your rhetorical question, I was wondering the same thing :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector like this to get all checked checkboxes with the specified name:

```
$("input[name='chkTextEffects']:checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY

```
$('input:checkbox:(:checked)').each( function() {
// your code here
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

http://www.wiseguysonly.com/2010/01/15/select-and-unselect-all-checkboxes-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
$("#checkboxId").attr("checked") == "checked";
```